# Is there a way to have NPTv6 with connection tracking on Linux?

Tags: ipv6, ip-conntrack

Apparently, the implementation of [NPTv6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6296) (Network Prefix Translation for IPv6) which is currently in Linux kernel is incompatible with connection tracking. This is quite disappointing, since I feel that NPTv6 is much more sane solution that NAT66, when you have dynamic IPv6 prefixes from the ISP and want to have stable internal IPv6 addresses.

I certainly don't want to do NAT66, but also need the stateful firewall, especially considering that NPTv6 preserves end-to-end connectivity, thus connection tracking is a must have.

My question is, does anyone know about any patches/add-ons/work-arounds that let me have NPTv6 and connection tracking for the translated flows, on the same host?

Comment: Where did you hear this rumor?

Comment: "man iptables-extensions" says this about DNPT: " You also have to use the NOTRACK target to disable connection tracking for translated flows."

Comment: Huh. I wonder what that's all about. Time to set up a lab, I suppose.

Comment: I don't get it at all. I tried searching on netfilter-dev, and found this: http://marc.info/?l=netfilter-devel&m=136787166726236&w=2

 Patrick McHardy (who led development of netfilter for a while) says this: "If you're using conntrack anyways, why use NPT? The main benefit is that you don't have to use conntrack."  -- I'm totally not getting what's going on here...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SNPT / DNPT was created specifically to be lightweight NPTv6, done exclusively in "mangle" table and is incompatible with connection tracking.

If connection tracking is employed, then there is a NETMAP target which can do IPv6 network prefix translation. So, the documentation is unclear on this, I suspect for political/religious reasons (NETMAP target is really a form of NAT66, which is disliked by many).

So, if `2607:xxx::/64` is external prefix, `fda3:xxx::/64` is internal prefix, and `eth0.99` is the outgoing interface, then the following does the job:

```
ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0.99 -j NETMAP --to 2607:xxx::/64 -s fda3:xxx::/64
ip6tables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0.99 -j NETMAP -d 2607:xxx::/64 --to fda3:xxx::/64
```

Now, to be clear: NETMAP does 1:1 address translation (NAT), but I'm not sure it follows RFC6296 with regards to being checksum-neutral, or how it diverges from RFC-compliant NPTv6 in some other way, but it's good enough for me, and it works.